# ReactJs Newbie Getting Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

All,  i am getting the following error in react js app. I am new to React and trying to create a sample app and running into this issue: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions.. Any pointer as to what happening.....
Sample Code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Post from "./Post";

function App() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([
    {
      username: "kmangal",
      caption: "wow this is working and cool",
      imageUrl: "{require('./images/antoers.jpg')}",
    },
    {
      username: "ROHINI",
      caption: "Rohie wow this is working and cool",
      imageUrl: "{require('./images/antoers.jpg')}",
    },
    {
      username: "GEETA",
      caption: "GEETA wow this is working and cool",
      imageUrl: "{require('./images/antoers.jpg')}",
    },
  ]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="app_header">
        <img className="app_header" src={require("./images/logo.png")} alt="" />
      </div>
      <h1>hellow this is khemlall</h1>

      {posts.map((post) => {
        <Post username={post.username} />;
      })}
      <Post
        username="kmangal"
        caption="wow this is working and cool"
        imageUrl={require("./images/antoers.jpg")}
      />
      <Post
        username="Rohini"
        caption="rohini mrry khemlall"
        imageUrl={require("./images/prot1.png")}
      />
      <Post
        username="geeta"
        caption="she is my sisster"
        imageUrl={require("./images/psot2.jpg")}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{posts.map((post) => {
  <Post username={post.username} />;
})}
```

This map function isn't returning anything. Either add a return statement in:

```
{posts.map((post) => {
  return <Post username={post.username} />;
})}
```

Or do the shortened version of an arrow function by removing the curly brackets

```
{posts.map((post) => (
  <Post username={post.username} />
))}
```

Comment: Thank you this works, {posts.map((post) => (
  <Post username={post.username} />
))} This works!